# migration Tuleap 6.11 -> Tuleap 7.3

Tags: migration, tuleap

I am currently using Tuleap 6.11 on a Red Hat 5.10 + php 5.1.6.

I want to migrate to Tuleap 7.3 on CentOS 6 + php 5.4

What is the best way :

- directly transfer 6.11 prodcution database to the new machine ?
- update Tuleap on my production machine and then transfer database to
  new machine ?
- install new machine in Tuleap 6.11, transfer database
  and then update Tuleap ?

Thanks for your comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my thoughts.

- php 5.4 isn't officially supported yet, so some things may not work.
- the database name in CentOS 5.* is "codendi" whereas on CentOS 6 it is "tuleap". Same for many folders.
- there's not just the db that needs to be transferred; many services such as svn, webdav or mediawiki store files directly on the file system.

The simplest thing to do is to upgrade the php version to php 5.3 on the current server then upgrade to a newer version of tuleap http://doc-en.tuleap.net/en/latest/installation-guide/advanced-installation.html?highlight=upgrade#upgrade-tuleap-from-php-to-php53-on-centos5 although that doesn't answer all that you want to do.